# Is this type of scratched pot safe?

Tags: pot

I found [What can I do about scratched pots?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20939/what-can-i-do-about-scratched-pots?newreg=a7cbd11f2e0c436e8285a02db1fdd036) But the type of pot, and level of scratch, is much different than that which was mentioned in that question.

Is this

[image: Image showing pot with heavily scratched black enamel]

Safe, at all, to cook with?

I tried describing it to a friend without showing him the picture and he said it might have harmful chemicals from the coating once it's scratched, but I don't know if that's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this looks like an enamel pot with some of the enamel gone. It shouldn't be losing any more enamel particles unless scratched some more, and even if it does, enamel is basically sand, so it is chemically neutral and likely harmless to swallow in small quantities.

Enamel on pots is used to prevent harmful chemical reactions between food and the base metal of the pot. For this reason the lack of enamel makes this pot unsuitable for cooking foods that react with steel or aluminium. It's likely OK to boil water or cook things with low acidity, but I wouldn't use it for soups, sauces, and such.

It also looks ugly. Why don't you just toss it?

Comment: thanks for the advice. I cant afford a new one, Im dirt poor. Do u think its safe for eggs , quinoa and greenbeans [all I really use it for] etc.?

Comment: @B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem it should be fine for those things